# Extjs Why my numberfeld don't accept decimals

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, extjs, numbers, decimal, field

I've got problem with my numberfield its looks like this
Extjs version 3.4

```
{
                xtype: 'numberfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Cena',
                name: 'Price',
                id: 'Price',
                allowNegative: false,
                width: 200,
                allowBlank: false,
                decimalPrecision:2,
                blankText: "Proszę podać cenę produktu"
            }
```

But when I put 99.99 then its not valid
only accept 99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the code you've posted. Tested it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YzeEm/), and it works:

```
Ext.create({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

    xtype: 'numberfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Cena',
    name: 'Price',
    id: 'Price',
    allowNegative: false,
    width: 200,
    allowBlank: false,
    decimalPrecision:2,
    blankText: "Proszę podać cenę produktu"
});
```

Comment: Ye sorry you are right I checked it too but when I put
to form 99.99
then in my action controller have value 0
but without precssion is ok 99 = 99